# error when i click on google sign in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-authentication

When I click on the "google sign in" button and then instead of continuing I click on "cancel", this error comes out: "PlatformException (PlatformException (sign_in_canceled, com.google.GIDSignIn, The user canceled the sign-in flow., Null))."

The code is this:

```
Future<UserCredential?> signInWithGoogle() async {
  try {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount? utenteGoogle = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? datiUtenteGoogle =
        await utenteGoogle?.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final credenzialiGoogle = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: datiUtenteGoogle?.accessToken,
      idToken: datiUtenteGoogle?.idToken,
    );

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credenzialiGoogle);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

I tried to catch the error but nothing